# SDL 2 с Android

Tags: android, android-ndk, sdl2

Кто собирал приложение на `Android` с `SDL`? Как связать нативный код своего приложение с контекстом Java приложения?
В моем случае, есть `libSDL2.so` и моя библиотека, использующая `SDL`, а также скомпилированная и собранная в `.so`, в котором (для начала) вызывается `SDL_Init` и `SDL_CreateWindow`

Под `Win32` (разумеется собранная в `dll`) это работает, вызываю метод с указанными вызовами функций и создается новое окно. Но таким же образом выполнив метод, сама функция срабатывает и завершает выполнение без выброшенных исключений, но визуально ничего не проявляется. В сети находил примеры только с использованием `Surface`, судя по `.java` активити классу (причем приложенные `.cpp` файлы отсутствуют), но и там мне пока непонятно, как это связывается, да и там события реализуются на `java` стороне

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При сборке `.so` библиотеки кроме своих `.cpp` файлов должен быть подключен [SDL_android.main.c](https://www.libsdl.org/tmp/SDL/src/main/android/SDL_android_main.c), который содержит метод `nativeInit`. Он же вызывается из [SurfaceView](https://github.com/emscripten-ports/SDL2/blob/master/android-project/src/org/libsdl/app/SDLActivity.java) класса в новом потоке